# Re-execute an observable to notify currently subscribed observers

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

In an Android app scenario, I want to fetch some `Observable<Data>` from network, and there are multiple `Observer<Data>` subscribed to it to update corresponding views. In case of error -say a timeout- show a button to the user to try again.

How can I do the try again part? can I tell the observable to re-execute its logic again without re-subscribing to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have two buttons, "Retry" and "Cancel", initially hidden. Create two `Observable`s `retryButtonClicks` and `cancelButtonClicks`. Then, apply the `retryWhen` operator to the designated download flow and act upon the signals of these button clicks:

```
download.retryWhen(errors -> {
    return errors
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(e -> {
            // show the "Retry" and "Cancel" buttons around here
            return Observable.amb(
                    retryButtonClicks.take(1).map(v -> "Retry"),
                    cancelButtonClicks.take(1).map(v -> "Cancel")
                )
                .doOnNext(v -> { /* hide the "Retry" and "Cancel" buttons */ });
    })
    .takeWhile(v -> "Retry".equals(v))
    ;
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's happening here? and how to create the buttons observables?

Comment: There is a stream of errors with `retryWhen`. If an error occurs, another flow is mapped in which takes the button click signal from either buttons unless cancel was clicked. Once the "Retry" button was clicked, the `retryWhen` will resubscribe to the source. Please look at the RxBinding library for creating button click `Observable`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and explanation

Comment: Another question, using `retryWhen` prevents the error from being propagated to the observer's `onError` callback. How to solve this while using `retryWhen`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Assume observable:
`Observable<Object> ob = Observable.create(e -> {
            e.onNext(1);
            e.onNext(2);
            e.onError(new Throwable("Intentional error"));
        }).retryWhen(....)`
with the retry logic you provided added to this observable.

And the observer:
`ob.subscribe(
                o -> Log.d(TAG, o.toString()),
                e -> Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage())
        );`

The "Intentional error" string doesn't get logged

Comment: In the `flatMap` inside `retryWhen`, check the `e` and return `Observable.error(e)` to stop the retry.

Comment: But i need to keep both, return the error to be consumed by the Observer, and then execute the retry when retry button clicked!

Comment: That is not possible. The moment the error reaches the Observer, the stream is over.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually specific methods

```
retry()
```

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable,
>   resubscribing to it if it calls onError (infinite retry count).

and `retry(long count)`

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable,
>   resubscribing to it if it calls onError up to a specified number of
>   retries.

Read more in an [article](http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/) and in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#retryWhen(rx.functions.Func1))

Comment: But these will retry directly after onError called, what I want to do is to retry when the button is clicked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809467/rxandroid-retry-observable-on-click

This worked for me but I used it for rxjs.